# ReactiveCocoa: Xcode asking me the conversion to swift 3

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

Evening, I'm working with a project using cocoapods, especially with the [SimpleAuth pod](https://github.com/calebd/SimpleAuth).

Now I can't understand why, after I installed my pods and updated them, opening the workspace I receive the warning:

[image]

While the [readme of ReactiveCocoa](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa) is saying that is swift 3 ready.

Mine reactiveCocoa version is 4.2.2, the latest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to change your Xcode 8.1 toolchain to use Swift 3.0.